# Mule: How to make sure payload is in writable state before doing file outbound

Tags: mule

In my `<catch-exception-strategy>`, I write error payload to `file`. But sometimes when flow involves web-service calls and host is unavailable or unknown (for e.g. `java.net.UnknownHostException` is thrown), payload is not anymore an instance of `InputStream` or `String`. If I try to log error then to file, following exception is thrown:

```
exception.AbstractExceptionListener (AbstractExceptionListener.java:299) - 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*'}".
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-65237
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*'}". (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
  org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper:252 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException: Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod, mimeType='*/*'}" to "SimpleDataType{type=java.io.InputStream, mimeType='*/*'}".
    at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.lookupTransformer(MuleRegistryHelper.java:252)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:355)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:313)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

I am thinking of doing a `choice` block before writing to file to make sure payload is writable. Shall I do something like `#[payload instanceof java.io.InputStream]`? But then how about cases where payload is `DOM` or something else? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a transformer inside the catch exception strategy and encapsulate there the logic that would consider the input and produce a writable payload.

Comment: you mean I have to take into account all the possible types that payload can be and convert them?

Comment: But my question is I just want to write to file when payload is writable, I don't want to transform payload

Comment: What would you when you can't write it?

Comment: just use a simple logger statment, can't write payload and come off

Comment: In that case I would suggest you two options, based on that the FileMessageDispatcher does in the doDispatch method:

https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/file/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/file/FileMessageDispatcher.java?source=c
//// 
a) Implement a custom FileMessageDispatcher to catch the exception and log a message when it fails to write and set use it on the connector
////
b) Use a similar logic to the one in the doDispatch in a message processor

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether there is a transformer available for a specific payload type and output type, I guess you could look up the available transformers from the registry. In Groovy:

```
transformers = message.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupTransformers(
   new org.mule.transformer.types.SimpleDataType(payload.getClass()), 
   new org.mule.transformer.types.SimpleDataType(java.io.InputStream))
if (transformers.size() == 0) {
  //set some variable or whatever
}
```